# coins output in vending maching?

Tags: java

I'm not sure where I'm wrong. I am not being able to get the proper output as expected. Below is my piece of program:

```
public static void insertMoney(){
    double dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;
   double paymentSum=0;
    System.out.println("Enter amount of money in cents.");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    paymentSum = input.nextDouble();
    //paymentSum = (paymentSum)/100;
       if (paymentSum <= 0){
        System.out.println("Please feed me more money, so I can feed you!. Try again next time :)");
        return; 
       }
    System.out.println("You entered: " +paymentSum+" Cent(s).");
    System.out.println((paymentSum/100) + " Cent(s) in coins can be given as: ");
   dollars = paymentSum /100;
   paymentSum = paymentSum%100;
    quarters = paymentSum/25;
    paymentSum = paymentSum % 25;
    dimes = paymentSum/10;
    paymentSum = paymentSum % 10;
    nickels = paymentSum/5;
    paymentSum = paymentSum % 5;
    pennies = paymentSum;
    System.out.println(dollars + " dollar(s)");
    System.out.println(quarters + " quarter(s)");
    System.out.println(dimes + " dime(s)");
    System.out.println(nickels + " nickel(s) and");
    System.out.println(pennies + " pennies");
}
```

I'm trying to get output as this:

```
You entered: 26.0 Cent(s).
0.26 Dollar(s) in coins can be given as: 
0.0 dollar(s)
1.0 quarter(s)
0.0 dime(s)
0.0 nickel(s) and
1.0 pennies
```

But I get this:

```
You entered: 26.0 Cents(s).
0.26 Dollar(s) in coins can be given as: 
0.26 dollar(s)
1.04 quarter(s)
0.1 dime(s)
0.2 nickel(s) and
1.0 pennies
```

What am I doing wrong in my code? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but `paymentSum` is a double, and you read in an int.

Comment: Oops! But still I'm getting the same result after reading paymentSum in Double.

Comment: You need to subtract the amounts that you take as you go along.  I would actually look up decimal to binary converters, as it is a similar concept.

Comment: I don't understand how that can be done. @ostrichofevil But it works fine when everything is in    int     . The problem came after I tired to input more than 100 cents. Cause I still have to write more code where an user have to select an item worth more than a dollar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is your expecting integer division but using a double `paymentSum`.
As noted in [this article](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-int-double-float-mixed-type-division-arithmetic-rules), since `paymentSum` is a double, any division will also produce a double. That's why your quarters are showing up as `1.04` instead of `1`, and why your dimes are `0.1` instead of `0`, etc...

Comment: Now I changed everything back to int and it works, but one issue I have now is I am not being able to get dollar amount. I mean, I did `dollars = (paymentSum/100)` and when entered 232 cents, i get only 2.0 as dollar amount.

Comment: try `dollars = (double)paymentSum / 100` or `dollars = paymentSum / 100.0`

Comment: Why -1? Is something in this answer incorrect or unclear?

Comment: I'm new in the community but I'm 100% sure that I didn't down voted it . All I did was mark the answer correct.

Comment: Thank you @JakeStrang This solves my problem. So, now Do I delete the post or what should I do? Since it's marked duplicate. And as per my question being as duplicate as in the given link, I'm quite not in that level yet.

Comment: Nope, just leave it ;) Here are some [guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) for dealing with duplicate questions